# Looping through dates

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date, datetime

I am trying to loop through some dates I created, but I get an error. This is the code:

```
q3_2018 = datetime.date(2018,9,30) 
q4_2018 = datetime.date(2018,12,31) 
q1_2019 = datetime.date(2019,3,31) 
q2_2019 = datetime.date(2018,6,30) 

dates = [q3_2018, q4_2018,q1_2019,q2_2019]
values = []


for d in dates:
    v =  fin[fin['Date of Completion 1 payment']<d]['1st payment amount:\n(70%)'].sum() 
    values.append(v)
```

where fin['Date of Completion 1 payment'] is a pandas column with payment dates and fin['1st payment amount:\n(70%)'] is a pandas column with amount paid.

I get the following error

> TypeError:  type object 2018-09-30

where's the mistake?

Comment: what is `fin.dtypes`?

Comment: 1st payment amount:\n(70%)             float64
Date of Completion 1 payment    datetime64[ns]
Final payment : (30%)                  float64
Date of completion              datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest convert `date`s to `datetimes` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then for select column use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime([q3_2018, q4_2018,q1_2019,q2_2019])
print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-03-31', '2018-06-30'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Or compare by `string`s:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime([q3_2018, q4_2018,q1_2019,q2_2019]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (dates)
Index(['2018-09-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-03-31', '2018-06-30'], dtype='object')
```

Or:

```
dates = ['2018-09-30', '2018-12-31' '2019-03-31','2018-06-30']
```

---

```
values = []
for d in dates:
    v =  fin.loc[fin['Date of Completion 1 payment']<d, '1st payment amount:\n(70%)'].sum() 
    values.append(v)
```

List comprehension solution:

```
values = [fin.loc[fin['Date of Completion 1 payment']<d, '1st payment amount:\n(70%)'].sum() 
          for d in dates]
```

---

Or upgrade to last version of pandas for compare with dates, check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0231-fixed-regressions):

```
# 0.22.0... Silently coerce the datetime.date
>>> Series(pd.date_range('2017', periods=2)) == datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

# 0.23.0... Do not coerce the datetime.date
>>> Series(pd.date_range('2017', periods=2)) == datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool

# 0.23.1... Coerce the datetime.date with a warning
>>> Series(pd.date_range('2017', periods=2)) == datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
/bin/python:1: FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'.  Currently, the
'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future pandas will
not coerce, and the values not compare equal to the 'datetime.date'.
To retain the current behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a
datetime with 'pd.Timestamp'.
  #!/bin/python3
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Not sure why it returns     axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))

KeyError: 'the label [Date of Completion 1 payment] is not in the [index]' while that column is clearly in the index (i check, no space issue, the column is spelled as it is)..

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - Check columns names by `print (df.columns.tolist())`, maybe some encoding or trailing space problem.

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - oops, typo on my side, `.loc` need in first `fin.loc[fin['Date of Completion 1 payment']<d, '1st payment amount:\n(70%)'].sum()`